# How to include keypad in layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

i am creating app, which requeres to display keypad all the time. For window i layout described in *.xml. How i can add keypad to this view?
for eg:

```
<layout>
  <textView/>
  <image/>
  <keypad/>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 2):

you cannot add the keyboard to your layout, and to force the keyboard to be always visible in a certain Activity by adding this to your `activity` element in the manifest:
`android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible"`